# How do I allow sign-ins from unusual locations in Google?

Tags: google-account, security, multi-factor-auth, proxy

I work for a company that provides internet to the users through proxy servers located in the USA and Switzerland, which results in all kinds of inconveniences, of which the most annoying is the fact that just can't log on to Google without using my IT Helpdesk powers to circumvent the proxy, which implies disconnecting from the company LAN. Google will block any attempt of signing in from the locations of the proxy servers. I'm not going to give the damned thing my phone number, and I'm not going to change my password each time I want to log on. I've recognized those sign-in attempts countless times, but the thing won't understand that if I've recognized them before, I might want them to stay recognized.

I've looked at the help pages and they keep saying there are options to turn this off. I don't see these options. One [says](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/45938?hl=en) there's a button below the recent activity list. There's none that I can see. One guy [wrote](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/turn-off-gmail-ip-address-tracker-51241.html) that if I go to the bottom of the main Gmail page... OK, I stopped right there. I don't have a Gmail account.

It's not even that I can't log on to Google, but that I can't log on to anything that uses Google credentials, like this site. How do I solve this?

Comment: Have you enabled two factor authentication?

Comment: Can you provide urls to the articles mentioned in your question?

Comment: @daxlerod It is off if you mean what Google calls a 2-step verification. To turn it on, as I understand, I would need to give Google my phone number, and I'd rather die.

Comment: I am pretty sure every `Google Account` comes with a `Google Mail Account` automatically.  You could always use Google Voice and use the Google Voice smart phone application, to recieve the text messages that are sent out.  I am pretty sure you can also use the Google Authenticator

Comment: You're being a bit dramatic. I'm talking about the code generator. You don't even have to use their implementation of the app. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Authenticator

Comment: @Ramhound I'm not sure how it works, but my Google account is older than Gmail. It did ask me whether I wanted Gmail a couple of times, and I kept saying no until it got bored. I am not in possession of a smartphone. I didn't know about Google Authenticator. Is there a way to use it without giving Google my personal details?

Comment: @daxlerod If there's a relatively simple way to use a Google Authenticator without giving Google my personal details and without using a smartphone or a dumbphone, please make it an answer.

Comment: @ymar your restrictions means basically Google is not interested in your business and you will have to deal with real security measures that everyone else accepts or create a desktop version of the Google Authenticator

Comment: @ramhound Please make it an answer if you're sure that is correct. I will accept it if nobody gives a solution.

Comment: @ymar - I am going to wait until an answer says something else other then you are S.O.L when it comes to this problem

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which proxy servers you use, but at our office we have a proxy toolbar by [geoedge](http://www.geoedge.com/) that allows us to disable the proxies on Google sites so we don't need to login all over everytime time we change proxy location.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is against company policy to install anything not approved by the corporation. It is also policy that while connected to the company network, we _cannot_ disable proxies. We cannot choose the servers either.