# How can I sign in to someone's Google Domains account who is in a different geographic area from me?

Tags: google-account, google-domains

I'm taking over hosting my sister's website. Her domain is registered with Google and she needs me to sign in to that account to update the A record to point to my server. Every time I try to sign in I get the following message:

> We detected an unusual sign-in attempt. To make sure that someone else isn't trying to access your account, your organization needs you to sign in using your corporate mobile device (the phone or tablet you normally use to access your corporate account).
>   If you don’t have your corporate mobile device with you right now, try again later when you have your corporate mobile device with you. If you continue to have problems signing in, contact your administrator.

So I message her and she doesn't have any notifications or emails about this but she signs in to her account on her phone. Nothing changes for me. I try to sign in again; same message. What do I need to do to be able to sign in to her account? Are there some additional steps necessary?

Comment: What do you mean by "Google Domains account"? Is this actually a G Suite account? What is the URL that you are using to sign in?

Comment: Related: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/50857/88163

Comment: @Rubén It's possible to register domains with Google and this is called Google Domains. There is, in this case, an associated G Suite account though. Which is likely a cause for elevated security I would think.

Comment: I'm glad that you we able to solve this.

Answer (score 2):

She needed to install the Google app on her iPhone. After she did this, she got the necessary prompt.